# PowerShell script to set all fields in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

This should be easy for someone :)  I just want a simple script to update all items in a SharePoint list to a certain value IF a condition is true.  Can someone assist?

List is "Project Initiation"
Condition to evaluate is if "Authorization" field is = "Pending"
Field to set is "Overall Status" to the string value "In Authorization"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$siteUrl = 'http://....'
$listName = 'Project Initiation'
$field1_Name = 'Authorization'
$field2_Name = 'Overall Status'

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$items = $list.Items
ForEach ($item in $items)
{
    if ($item[$field1_Name].ToString() -eq 'Pending')  
    {
       $item[$field2_Name] = "In Authorization"
       $item.Update()
    }
}
$web.Dispose()
```